# Adding Content To The DOM Using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add an `<h2>` element after the second `<p>` in each `<article>` element. Can someone explain why `article p:nth-child(3)` works? At first glance I would think this syntax points to the third `<p>`in each `<article>`. Also, are there more efficient ways of doing this? Trying to get a better grasp of JQuery. Thanks.

```js
    (function(){
      $('<h2></h2>', {
        text: 'hello',
        class: 'million'
      }).insertAfter('article p:nth-child(3)');
    })();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <article>
    <h1>My Awsome Post</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </p>
    <p>
      Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
      consequat
    </p>
    <p>
      Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
      consequat
    </p>
  </article>
  <article>
    <h1>My Awsome Post</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </p>
    <p>
      Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
      consequat
    </p>
    <p>
      Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
      consequat
    </p>
  </article>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: See http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Answer (score 2):

`nth-child` will select the child element of the parent in position `n`, no matter what the other child tags are.

You are simply restricting it to also match `p` tags, in other words, select the 3rd child of each `article` which is a `p` tag. Because you have an `h1` at the start of each article, the 3rd child becomes the 2nd `p`.

If you want the second *`p`* tag, then you can use the [`:nth-of-type`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-of-type-selector/) selector - `p:nth-of-type(2)`. As the docs on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-of-type) for this selector say:

> This is a more flexible and useful pseudo selector [than nth-child] if you want to ensure you're selecting the same type of tag no matter where it is inside the parent element, or what other different tags appear before it.

This should do what you need:

```js
    (function(){
      $('<h2></h2>', {
        text: 'hello',
        class: 'million'
      }).insertAfter('article p:nth-of-type(2)');
    })();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <article>
    <h1>My Awsome Post</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </p>
    <p>
      Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
      consequat
    </p>
    <p>
      Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
      consequat
    </p>
  </article>
  <article>
    <h1>My Awsome Post</h1>
    <h2>Some sub-heading to increase the number of other children</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </p>
    <p>
      Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
      consequat
    </p>
    <p>
      Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
      consequat
    </p>
  </article>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. Good explanation